# I'm trying to join to tables but can get expected result

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect to tables using SQL Joins.
Table No.1

```
event_id | emp_id | event_date |
00000001 | 000002 | 2019-05-31 |
```

Table No.2

```
emp_id | emp_name |
000001 | a
000002 | b
```

My code is something like this

```
"Select table2.emp_id,table2.emp_name from table2 left join table1 
on tabl2.emp_id = table1.emp_id where event_date <> '2019-05-31'"
```

My desire output is something like this:

```
emp_id | emp_name
000001 | a
```

But its giving me blank result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add to the where clause the case `event_date is null`:

```
select table2.emp_id, table2.emp_name 
from table2 left join table1 
on table2.emp_id = table1.emp_id 
where table1.event_date is null or table1.event_date <> '2019-05-31'
```

since you are using a `left join`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jX95teuec43QAD6ntWWkVY/0).
Results:

```
| emp_id | emp_name |
| ------ | -------- |
| 000001 | a        |
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the condition `event_date <> '2019-05-31'` in the `WHERE`, you can use it with the `AND`,  then you will get your expected result:

```
Select table2.emp_id,table2.emp_name  
from table2 
left join table1 on tabl2.emp_id = table1.emp_id AND event_date <> '2019-05-31'
```

If you are adding the condition on WHERE clause it will filter from the both the tables, so the LEFT JOIN will not return your expected result

Comment: You cannot have 2 on clauses in a join?

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry typo, I typed `ON` instead of `AND`. Thanks for the notification

Comment: Tried it, now this is the output.

emp_id | emp_name
000001 | a
000002 | b

cant Get the desired out put .

emp_id | emp_name
000001 | a

Answer (score 0):

Is emp_id 000001 in the left table? If not then you won't see it as you are specifically pulling the results from the left table (with a left join)

try and remove the word 'left':

```
    Select table2.emp_id,table2.emp_name from table2
    join table1
    on tabl2.emp_id = table1.emp_id 
    where event_date <> '2019-05-31'
```